# Claiming apartment rent as unreimbursed employee expense

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, benefits

a friend of mine visited a tax consultant in USA. The friend is an employee of a software firm and is on a non-resident alien category visa. The consultant told him to mark the apartment rent as unreimbursed employee expense and add it in the itemized deductions. The house he stays in is not provided by the company but the consultants argument was that the employee rented the apartment since he has to commute to work and occasionally does work from home,  so it is a valid expense. It sounds fishy to me. Any advice?

Comment: Unless there are drtails you haven't included here which make this clearly a business expense rather than a convenience that advice is worse than wrong.

Comment: I think it depends on the details.  I deducted a room rental expense for about 18 months, but I maintained my permanent residence about 250 miles from the job site (so not viable as a daily commute), and only spent about every other week there.

Comment: Tax questions require that you specify the country.

Comment: @keshlam, what kind of details will not make it a business expense.  I can ask him

Comment: @chris added the details, the country is USA

Comment: The question is missing some key details. Friend is a non-resident alien, ok. He rents the apartment, but has to commute? Does this mean he has two residents in the US? A bit of clarification might help.

Comment: The logical thing to do here is to gt a second opinion from a professional. I would also ask what professional qualifications this consultant has, and whether he is providing this advice in writing.

Comment: Unless the apartment is taken for the employer's convenience rather than the employee's, or is otherwise required rather than merely being a convenience, US tax law is unlikely to consider it a business expense. Generally the answer is "not deductible " unless the commute is completely unreasonable or you may need to be on site at a moment's notice. And remember that some Americans do tolerate commutes of an hour or more.